# Ubuntu Phone as PC

Tags: ubuntu-touch, monitor, phone

I feel "smart-phones" are computers, but none of OS is made to support desktop applications. Will Ubuntu Phone have that feature in near future. Will we be able just to connect phone to a monitor and work with it in office ?

Comment: Hmm... I think in when they were first on about the Ubuntu Edge and Ubuntu Touch/Ubuntu for Android, part of the intended functionality was to be able to use the phone as a desktop computer (this showed in [one of the promo videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iv1Z7bf4jXY) at least - also demonstrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzc0uMXGFBY)  . This idea may of gone out of the window somewhat due to the needed hardware support, as [the Aquaris E4.5](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/devices) (and other devices available) may not work with this idea.

Comment: I know that, I saw it also. That's why I was disappointed when I saw specs of final product.  Imagine how many firms, freelancers and institutions would get Ubuntu Phone if it was built over desktop environment. I'd throw all my old equipment and get rid of cables. And it's not just me. I think all linux fans and high percentage of other users would start using it. Ubuntu Phone could literally demolish competitors.

Comment: I know it's been a few years, but I just saw this yesterday, and have now provided an accurate answer to your question, which is a lengthier version of "yes, this is now possible to do, today."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless phones move away from the ARM processor architecture and are equipped with HDMI or VGA outputs, we will always have separate apps and OSes for them. The reason many apps aren't available for phones is because developers don't want the extra work of compiling their apps for ARM. Normal Ubuntu can't be installed on phones because of how they work. If mobile devices went to Intel or AMD processors, then normal Ubuntu would work, but until that happens fully (which will be a while) we're not going to see normal Ubuntu on phones anytime soon.

Comment: But applications have to follow OS structure, not processors. Compiling apps depends of OS.

Comment: Also adding video output would increase price of phone but wouldn't need software upgrade as Ubuntu already have pretty solid solution. Higher price for  out of a box phone-pc  shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Applications designed for desktop processors will not run on the ARM architecture, so it's definitely a requirement. The reason the OS is different is because of the processor architecture. So yes, I guess the OS design prevents certain apps from running, but the design is different because of the arch.

Comment: This is wildly off base. For many people their computing needs can be fully met by phone or tablet devices. Also, on Ubuntu Touch, the goal is to build converged applications. Most all the default apps are already also usable on PC with roughly the same experience as on phones.

Comment: @dobey I never said phones weren't enough for most people. I said full Ubuntu isn't made to run on them. Ubuntu Touch was discontinued.

Comment: No, it wasn't. Canonical ceased development in 2017 (two years after you answered this question), and UBports now develops and maintains it. Using a phone like a PC doesn't require all x86 apps to available/usable, nor traditional distros to be available to run on it.

Comment: Android is a mobile OS, that runs on x86; likewise, even Ubuntu itself runs on many different CPU architectures. Also, there are many mobile devices with mini HDMI outputs.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this properly, yes, it is possible to use a phone as a PC replacement, if all your computing needs can be met by the apps available, and hardware. [Ubuntu Touch](https://ubuntu-touch.io) is still actively developed and supported by [UBports](https://ubports.com) community, and still with the goal of building a converged OS and applications.

Included is an experimental feature, [Libertine](https://github.com/ubports/libertine), which allows to install legacy applications in a container. These generally do not work well on a phone screen, and the feature is still quite buggy, but it provides a way to run some necessary legacy applications when needed. When connecting a phone to an external display, keyboard, and mouse, these applications are much more usable. However, ideally fully converged native applications would be available to use, so you could work on any screen with any input methods, whenever you needed to.

As for the hardware side, it depends on the phone/tablet being used. If your devices supports wired external display, either directly or via Slimport or MHL adapters, you should be able to get a nice full resolution external display. For devices which don't support that, UT does have Miracast support, which presents a compressed/scaled windowed mode view over WiFi. For keyboard/mouse options, this again depends on the hardware. Devices that need to use wireless display will be more responsive with USB OTG adapter to use wired mouse and keyboard. Devices with wired display and direct display out (mini-HDMI or mini-DisplayPort) that also have a USB port can use either wired or Bluetooth keyboard and mouse. Devices which require a Slimport or MHL adapter over micro-USB, will require Bluetooth keyboard and mouse. And devices which have USB 3.0 or 3.1 on type C connector, with Slimport, HDMI alt mode, MHL, etc… should be able to use either wired or Bluetooth mouse and keyboard. These may also be able to use wired ethernet via a docking station, such as the Samsung DeX dock. Beware adapters and hubs that require *DisplayLink* though, as it is a proprietary protocol, and no drivers available when running Ubuntu Touch, though they may work OK if you want to use an Android device in this manner.

Given all the above, yes, it is very much possible to use a phone as a replacement for a PC, and even Android itself is moving more toward this possibility. For Ubuntu Touch, see the list of [supported devices](https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io), in case you want to choose one to try this with.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this new Linux phone made by SageTea, a top-notch IT company based in Canada.
What really caught my attention is that SageTea is super passionate about open-source software. They’ve built a phone called XFone that embraces open-source software as one of its standout features. So users can actually dig into the source code, make tweaks, and even enhance the software themselves.
In addition, they are saying that they will support external monitors with their phone as a key fix is made by the Ubuntu Touch Pixe 3A team.
So, if you’re into the idea of a Linux phone that puts privacy and open-source software first, you should check XFone from SageTea.